# give write access to another disk with ubuntu 20.04

Tags: filemanager, chmod

I'm new to linux and I'm struggling a bit with this problem. I have an HP HP EliteBook 840 G3 with an SDD disk on which I have installed ubuntu 20.04 and a hard disk on which I have windows. the hard disk containing windows has three partitions which I can access on my linux system. the problem is that i can't write to the other disk from ubuntu.
I tried to do a "chmod" but I have the message "chmod: modification of the rights of 'folder': File system accessible in read only.

Comment: As always, disabling Windows' Fast Startup feature is a must when dual-booting. That said you should avoid writing to the Windows system partition (typically C:\).

Comment: If a file-system is READ ONLY, it's because of a (1) mount choice by the operator, (2) the file-system has issues discovered & RO prevents damage; this includes a *fs* in *unclean* state, such as a hibernated/fastboot system where part of filesystem is in fastboot/hibernate file & not fully saved, or (3) errors were detected, so explore the reasons; did you mount it RO and not RW, is it *unclean* or did it mount RW and then *flip* to RO??  fyi:  `chmod` is a command to change data on the file-system, ie. RW is required before you can change anything!

Comment: thank you, it helped me a lot